# FFMPEG "Could find no file with path" and "No such file or directory"

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I try to convert a sequence of pictures to video file. 
But I get from `ffmpeg` the response, that no such file or directory

Does someone have a solution for it?

**My command line:**

```sh
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 0 -i "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\%3d.png" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\out.mp4
```

**The error:**

```
        C:\Users\USER>ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 0 -i "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\%3d.png" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\out.mp4
    ffmpeg version git-2020-05-01-39fb1e9 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
      built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
      configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
      libavutil      56. 43.100 / 56. 43.100
      libavcodec     58. 82.100 / 58. 82.100
      libavformat    58. 42.101 / 58. 42.101
      libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
      libavfilter     7. 80.100 /  7. 80.100
      libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
      libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
      libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
    [image2 @ 000002169186c440] Could find no file with path 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\%3d.png' and index in the range 0-4
    C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\%3d.png: No such file or directory
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%3d` means a *file name with 3 digits* (range `000` to `999`).

**solution A** : You must rename your files as `001.png` or `016.png` (not as `1.png` or `16.png`).

**solution B** : Use `%d` to avoid needing zeroes (no renaming). 
`-i "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Pictures\%d.png"`