# error with ffmpeg converting images to video

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, video, ffmpeg

I have this code that I am using to convert multiple images in different folders into videos. this is the code i have:

```
counter = 0
list_of_videos = os.listdir('./Pending/')

# obtain list of completed videos and strip extensions 
completed_mp4s = os.listdir('./outputvideos/')
completed_mp4s = [x[:len(x) - 4] for x in completed_mp4s]

# for videos that haven't been created, create video! if it exists, skip creation process
framerate = 30


for video in list_of_videos:
    if video not in completed_mp4s:
        counter += 1
        inputos = "ffmpeg -framerate " + str(framerate) + " -pattern_type sequence -i ./Pending/" + video + "/" + video + ".%d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p ./outputvideos/" + video + ".mp4"
        os.system(inputos)

print(counter)
```

however I have the same issue as this [FFMPEG "Could find no file with path" and "No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61568273/ffmpeg-could-find-no-file-with-path-and-no-such-file-or-directory)

The images are named as follows:

[image: image of names]

and the error I receive is this:

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.1 (GCC) 20200726
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --enable-librav1e --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
[image2 @ 000001dbf1f854c0] Could find no file with path './Pending/WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left/WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left.%d.png' and index in the range 0-4
./Pending/WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left/WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left.%d.png: No such file or directory
```

This is my folder structure:

[image: folder structr]

but when I tried the solutions provided , like changing the %04 to %4d or %d, the same problem persists. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thank you! :)

Comment: Can you post example of your folder structure?

Comment: yup sure! added @BijayRegmi

Comment: Replace `WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left.%d.png` with `WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left.%04d.png`. There are many reasons it might fail. Please post a minimal reproducible code sample. For making it reproducible, I recommend you to start by creating sample images using FFmpeg: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=10 WYZCW_Colored_Lights_Left.%4d.png` (may add it to the Python code). For keeping things minimal, start with one folder, were the images are in the working directory.